# react-table not updating from local json file

Tags: json, reactjs, react-hooks, react-table

I have hosted static website with react-table in github-pages.
the react-table renders data from the repository.

The data is updated once a day, but the updated contents does not seem to be reflected in the static website.

Here is my code,

```
import { useTable, usePagination, useSortBy } from 'react-table'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import mydata from "./mydata/data.json";
import styled from "styled-components";


const Styles = styled.div`

  .page-link {
    color: black;

  }

`




function Table({ columns, data }) {
    const {
        getTableProps,
        getTableBodyProps,
        headerGroups,
        prepareRow,
        page,
        canPreviousPage,
        canNextPage,
        pageOptions,
        pageCount,
        gotoPage,
        nextPage,
        previousPage,
        setPageSize,
        state: { pageIndex, pageSize },
    } = useTable(
        {
            columns,
            data,
            initialState: {
                pageIndex: 0,
                pageSize: 10,
                sortBy: [
                    {
                        id: 'date',
                        desc: true
                    }
                ]
            },
        },
        useSortBy,

        usePagination

    )
    // Render the UI for your table
    return (
        <div>
            <table className="table" {...getTableProps()}>
                <thead>
                    {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
                        <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                            {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                                <th {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())}>
                                    {column.render('Header')}
                                    <span>
                                        {column.isSorted
                                            ? column.isSortedDesc
                                                ? ' '
                                                : ' '
                                            : ''}
                                    </span>

                                </th>
                            ))}
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </thead>
                <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
                    {page.map((row, i) => {
                        prepareRow(row)
                        return (
                            <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                                {row.cells.map(cell => {
                                    return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                                })}
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            {/* 
        Pagination can be built however you'd like. 
        This is just a very basic UI implementation:
      */}
            <ul className="pagination">
                <li className="page-item" onClick={() => gotoPage(0)} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
                    <a className="page-link">First</a>
                </li>
                <li className="page-item" onClick={() => previousPage()} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
                    <a className="page-link">{'<'}</a>
                </li>
                <li className="page-item" onClick={() => nextPage()} disabled={!canNextPage}>
                    <a className="page-link">{'>'}</a>
                </li>
                <li className="page-item" onClick={() => gotoPage(pageCount - 1)} disabled={!canNextPage}>
                    <a className="page-link">Last</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a className="page-link">
                        Page{' '}
                        <strong>
                            {pageIndex + 1} of {pageOptions.length}
                        </strong>{' '}
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a className="page-link">
                        <input
                            className="form-control"
                            type="number"
                            defaultValue={pageIndex + 1}
                            onChange={e => {
                                const page = e.target.value ? Number(e.target.value) - 1 : 0
                                gotoPage(page)
                            }}
                            style={{ width: '100px', height: '20px' }}
                        />
                    </a>
                </li>{' '}
                <select
                    className="form-control"
                    value={pageSize}
                    onChange={e => {
                        setPageSize(Number(e.target.value))
                    }}
                    style={{ width: '120px', height: '38px' }}
                >
                    {[5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50].map(pageSize => (
                        <option key={pageSize} value={pageSize}>
                            Show {pageSize}
                        </option>
                    ))}
                </select>
            </ul>
        </div >
    )
}

function PaginationTableComponent() {



    const columns = React.useMemo(
        () => [
            {
                Header: 'Date',
                accessor: 'date',
                //  width: 100,
            },
            {
                Header: 'Title2',
                accessor: 'title',
                className: "title",
                //  width: 250,
                Cell: ({ row }) => <a href={row.original.url}>{row.original.title}</a>,
            },
            {
                Header: 'Title(en)',
                accessor: 'translated',
                className: "title",
                // width: 250,  
            },
            {
                Header: 'Likes',
                accessor: 'likes',
                //  width: 60,

            },

        ],
        [mydata]
    )



    const data = React.useMemo(
        () => mydata,
        [mydata]
    )



    return (
        <Styles>
            <Table columns={columns} data={data} />
        </Styles>
    )
}

export default PaginationTableComponent;
```

The main point here is that usememo is not detecting the changes from 'mydata'

'mydata' is a raw json file, something like the below.

```
[{"date":"2021-07-26","title":"Auth0\u306e\u30c8\u30fc\u30af\u30f3\u306b\u30ed\u30fc\u30eb\u3092\u8ffd\u52a0\u3067\u304d\u306a\u304f\u306a\u3063\u3066\u30cf\u30de\u3063\u305f\u4ef6 #Auth0 #Qiita\u30a8\u30f3\u30b8\u30cb\u30a2\u30d5\u30a7\u30b9\u30bf_Auth0","likes":0,"url":"https:\/\/dev.classmethod.jp\/articles\/stuck-add-user-roles-to-tokens\/","translated":"I was addicted to not being able to add roles to Auth0 tokens # Auth0 # Qiita Engineer Festa_Auth0"},{"date":"2021-07-26","title":"\u30ef\u30fc\u30b1\u30fc\u30b7\u30e7\u30f3\u30921\u5e74\u9593\u3084\u3063\u3066\u307f\u305f","likes":0,"url":"https:\/\/dev.classmethod.jp\/articles\/workation\/","translated":"I tried worcation for a year"},{"date":"2021-07-26","title":"ECR \u30af\u30ed\u30b9\u30a2\u30ab\u30a6\u30f3\u30c8\u30ec\u30d7\u30ea\u30b1\u30fc\u30b7\u30e7\u30f3\u3092Terraform\u3067","likes":0,"url":"https:\/\/dev.classmethod.jp\/articles\/ecr-cross-account-replication-with-terraform\/","translated":"ECR cross-account replication in Terraform"},{"date":"2021-07-26","title":"\u5b9f\u8df5\uff01AWS CDK #22 RDS \u30af\u30e9\u30b9\u30bf\u30fc","likes":3,"url":"https:\/\/dev.classmethod.jp\/articles\/cdk-practice-22-rds-cluster\/","translated":"Practice! AWS CDK # 22 RDS cluster"}]
```

Can anyone help solve this issue?

FYI, Attempts that I have tried :

1. I have included [mydata] as the second parameter for both useMemo components (columns, data)but it does not work.
2. Someone here mentioned that useMemo does not work with 'sortby', but I do not know how to apply this code to mine. ([React.useMemo does not update the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60435481/react-usememo-does-not-update-the-data))
3. maybe I thought it was because useMemo does not recognize raw json, but only recognizes javascript objects. That is why I followed this url ([How to use react-table for a local json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67610911/how-to-use-react-table-for-a-local-json-file)) but even after preprocessing the file, it does not work.

Comment: Are you creating a new build and deploy it whenever you update the json?

Comment: No i am not creating a new build and deploying. I build/deploy it once and only the json file gets updated.

Comment: The build wont know that the JSON file is updated. You import is resolved only at the time of building your app. Here you can have two solutions. 1. Create an API to Update and Read the JSON file. 2. You can still serve your JSON as a static file in your public folder. Fetch the file like `fetch('<your_gh_page_url>.<filename>.json').then((res)=>{console.log("bingo!!", res.data)})`

Comment: @hari thank you for your comment. I have changed as below but still useMemo does not work 

    const [mydata, setData] = useState([])
    
    const fetchData = () => {
        axios.get("data/data.json")
            .then(res => setData(res.data))
            .then(console.log(mydata))
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData()
    }, []);